# Entity Framework nulling relationship instead of deleting

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-core

I have a class which represents a company, that company has a list of Company Users. I can add users to the company without problems and I can even remove users from the company. However, the issue is when I remove a user their record remains in the database but with a null instead of a foreign key.

Here is the Company class

```
public class Company : BaseModel
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string UniqueId { get; set; }
    public virtual List<Location> CompanyLocations { get; set; }
    public virtual List<CompanyUser> CompanyUsers { get; set; }
}
```

And the CompanyUsers

```
public class CompanyUser : BaseModel
{
    public string UserId { get; set; }
    public virtual Company Company { get; set; }
}
```

And here is an example of the issue.

[image]

As you can see there are several rows with a null in the CompanyId field. I want the entire row to be deleted rather than just the relationship removed.

I assume there is something I can add in `OnModelCreate` that will fix this relationship, but I do not know what that is.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: You are looking for foreign keys with `cascading delete`. Your original migration should specify what kind of action to perform on delete, and it's most likely set to No Action right now. You can either re-do the migration, or use EFCore Fluent Api in `OnModelCreate` as you said:  `builder.Entity<Company>().WithMany(c => c.CompanyUsers).WithOne(cu => cu.Company).OnDelete(CascadeAction.Delete);`

Comment: Thanks for the response, I added something similar and it is now working `builder.Entity<CompanyUser>().HasOne(e => e.Company).WithMany(f => f.CompanyUsers).OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.Cascade);` . I suppose I will also add what you suggested since I also want it to delete when a Company is deleted.

Answer (score -1):

You should remove the Users from the `Users` dbset and not from the company users relationship. For example if we have a `CompanyUser` variable called `companyUser` to remove it you should do something like this

```
this.context.Users.Remove(companyUser);
this.context.SaveChanges();
```

and not something like this

```
var company = this.context.Companies.Find(companyUser.Company.UniqueId)
company.CompanyUsers.Remove(companyUser);
this.context.SaveChanges();
```

in the second example, you are only setting the foreign key relationship between a `CompanyUser` and a `Company` to null. But in the first example you are deleting the entire `CompanyUser` record from the database.

Comment: This is not what I want, the comment on my question should be the answer. I do not want to delete the user, only their relationship to a company. The issue was it left a row in the table with a null relationship. Updating the `OnDelete` resolved the issue.